# Read ENUM and its fields from a database (JPA)

Tags: java, database, jpa, enums

I have a model object that's in fact an enum with fields and getters:

```
@Entity
public enum Type {
   TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3, TYPE4;

   @Column
   private Long id;
   @Column
   private String name;
   ...

   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }
   ...
}
```

It compiles and runs fine. However, if I call a getter method, it returns null (it doesn't load any values stored in the database). Is this the standard behavior? Is there a way to make JPA load them?

Comment: what database representation do you expect?

Comment: The records (TYPE1, TYPE2 etc) are already in the database (it's a legacy database used by more applications) and therefore there are two alternatives to know which record is which: I can have named constants of type Long (storing `id` values) combined with a standard model object or an enum model object. I'd rather use the ENUM solution though.

Comment: Argh! Don't do this! Don't misuse enums like that!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sean, could you please elaborate on your "it's a misuse" comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say there is some misconception in this aproach:

1. Entities represent objects that can be stored in the database. In this case, the database (or any other persistent store) defines which instances are available.
2. Enums represent a fixed set of constants that are defined in source code. Thus the class itself defines which constants are available. In addition, it's generally bad practice to change the values of an enum, i.e. the name or id in your case.

You see that they are two quite different concepts which should be treated differently.

To store enums in entities (where the enum is a field of that entity), you could either use `@Enumerated` and store the name or ordinal of the enum, or (what we do more often) store one of the fields (we mostly use the id) and provide conversion methods.

If you want to store configurable "constants" in the database you might try and use plain entities for that, make the constructor private (Hibernate and other JPA providers should be able to deal with that) and provide an alternative implementation of the `Enum` class (you can't use the `enum` keyword though).

Comment: Never a misconseption, always some use.

Enums will typicall also exist as a set of rows with attrutes in a table. It is conceptionally possible, that with two different installations (two different customers, two different customizations), these attributes will be differnt. Thus the need for the Java Enum to be in sync with the DB enum. A known set of Enums, different attributes.

So conceptionally I see something I might need. In fact a specific search led me here.

I also do understand the conceptional issues with linking those to a

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the @Enumerated annotation? I haven't ever tried to use it within an enum itself, however it works quit well binding a class property to an enum.

```
enum Type{TYPE1, TYPE2}

@Column(name="type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Type getType(){return type;}
public void setType(Type t){type = t;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If JPA cannot be made to handle this, you could add a `public Type valueOf(long id)` method to your enum class which you use as a factory to instantiate enum instances representing the values in your legacy table.

Comment: Thanks, although I'd rather just use constants then. However, the question is: Can JPA be made to handle this?